Double integral of a gaussian-like integral
I am working with RKHS spanned by gaussian kernel $k(x,y)=\exp^{-\gamma^2(y-x)^2}$.
I would like to compute the value of the double integral :
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 e^{-\gamma^2(y-x)^2} dx dy $$
where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.
I tried with a change of variable in order to get a Gauss integral but i didn't find a suitable change of variable.

Simple frame rotation would let you have the integrand in the Gaussian form, however the area you have is a square and by no means is expandable to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is where the Gaussian is analytically tractable.

If I want to have an expression, I will have something non explicit ? Probably with the error function right ?

Actually, I think I've rushed to tell you it's untractable. If you rotate your frame by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$, you'll get an expression that is dependent on one variable only, leading you to a integral of the form $\int_a^b (v)\exp{(-\gamma^2 v^2)} dv$ which quite integrable.

What do you mean by rotate your frame ?

I'm gonna sketch out the solution, the questions are welcome in the comments:
First, apply the change of variables in the following form:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{}
u&=& x-y \\
v&=& x+y
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and calculate the Jacobian determinant to account for the elementary volume transformation. To do so requires expressing the $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{}
x&=& \dfrac{v+u}{2} \\
y&=& \dfrac{v-u}{2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
And then taking all the partial derivatives:
$$
|\det{J}| = 
\Bigg|
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{array}
\Bigg| = \Bigg|
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\Bigg|
$$
But since the determinant is a polylinear function of rows and columns, I can take out the common multiplier from entirt row or column. The first row has the common multiplier of $\frac{1}{2}$ and, incidentally, so does the second row. Hence,  $\frac{1}{2} \cdot  \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} $
$$
|\det{J}| = \frac{1}{4}
\Bigg|
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -1 \\
1 &  1
\end{array}
\Bigg| = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Now, the integral becomes:
$$
I=\frac{1}{2} \int_a^b \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}\left[\int_{\varphi_{1}(u)}^{\varphi_{2}(u)}dv \right] du
$$
To determine the new boundaries, let's take a look at the image of the transform. That is a rhombus, that is given by the equation: $|u|+|v-1|=1$. If you don't feel confident enough to tell that right away, consider the corner points images under the map and use the fact that this map is continuous and maps the edge of the square into the edge of the rhombus. Now that we know that one of our variables is not in the integrand (that is $v$), choose the boundaries in such a way that linear terms appear in the integral.
Here's what we do: as we see from the image of the rhombus, while $u$ spans from $-1$ to $1$, the $v$ travels between two lines. To elaborate, when $u$ spans from $-1$ to $0$, it is bounded by the line $v=-u$ from below and $v=u+2$ from above. Similarly, when $u$ spans from $0$ to $1$, the $v$ is restricted by $v=2-u$ from above and $v=u$ from below. Summing up, the integral now breaks into two:
$$
I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{0} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}\left[\int_{-u}^{u+2}dv \right] du + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}\left[\int_{u}^{2-u}dv \right] du
= \\
\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{0} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}(2u+2) \, du + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}(2-2u) \,du
$$
Changing the variables in the first integral by $u=-t$, one gets:
$$
I = 
 \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{t^2}}(1-t) \, dt + \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}(1-u) \, du
 = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}(1-u) \, du
$$
Now, breaking the integral into two:
$$
I = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}(1-u) \, du =
2 \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}} \, du - \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}} 2u \, du = \\
\frac{2}{\gamma} \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}} \, d(\gamma u) + \frac{1}{\gamma^2} \int_{0}^{1} \, e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}  d(-\gamma^2u^2) =\\
\frac{2}{\gamma} \int_{0}^{\gamma} \, e^{-t^2} \, dt + \frac{1}{\gamma^2} e^{-{\gamma^2}{u^2}}\Bigg|_{0}^{1} = \\
\Bigg| \text{using here the fact that } \text{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x} \, e^{-t^2} \, dt\Bigg| =\\
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\gamma} \text{erf}(\gamma) + \frac{1}{\gamma^2} \left(e^{-\gamma^2} - 1 \right)
$$
I think that does it.

Not a proof, but the simplest sanity check: at $\gamma = 0$ the first term expands to $\frac{\text{erf}(\gamma)}{\gamma} \approx \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ and the second yields $(e^{-\gamma^2} - 1) \approx (1-\gamma^2 + o(\gamma^2) - 1) \approx -\gamma^2 + o(\gamma^2)$ in the numerator. The entire second term now yields  $\frac{e^{-\gamma^2} - 1}{\gamma^2} \approx -1 + o(1)$ which in sum with the first one gives $1$. Notice, that if we were to place the $\gamma=0$ in the initial integral, that would give the area of the square.

Thank you for your detailed answer. Why do you have 1/4 when you compute the det of the jacobian ?

I added some detailed explanation into the answer.

This is very clear, thank you !
